# DNS Server keeps changing to 10.0.22.1 & .2 in OSX 10.9

Tags: network, dns

My DNS Server keeps changing to 10.0.22.1 & 10.0.22.2 in OSX 10.9.5. This causes me to *regularly* lose internet access until I go into the network preferences pane and delete the two "incorrect" DNS address which cause the **correct** addresses to automatically re-appear. Then after re-starting my browser, all is well again. If I check my network settings again, the incorrect DNS address have almost always re-appeared by themselves but loss of internet hasn't necessarily occurred. I've checked the DNS settings in my Apple Airport and they are correct and haven't changed and I've also cleared all caches but that doesn't seem to make a difference.

**Please HELP!**

Comment: It sounds like you have some sort of software that's adding the bad DNS servers to your network settings. Are you running any VPN software, or something like that? Also, is there anything you do that correlates with (and maybe triggers) the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I discovered that the VPN that I'm running (ProXPN) changes the DNS settings to the ones I mentioned in my original post when I enable it thru its own software. I contacted their tech support who confirmed this. The VPN does not allow me to specify my own settings or disable the settings it loads. They explained that their DNS server is "secure." They also said that their settings are ***supposed*** to return to normal when disabling the VPN.  Unfortunately they do not. So in the mean time, when I disconnect from the VPN, I have to go into the network pref pane and manually delete the VPN-set DNS addresess at which point, the correct ones appear automatically.

Tech Support said, "They'd look into it."

Thanks everybody for your input. I'll post anything if ProXPN Tech Support comes up with a solution.

JAY

Answer (score 0):

Reset your router. If you're set to DHCP then you're probably getting those IPs from the router. Failing that, create a new account on the machine and see if the same issue is present. All of that will help determine if the issue is likely user-, system-, or network-wide.

Comment: Actually, since removing them in Network Preferences makes the correct ones appear, it's almost certainly *not* from DHCP, but something locally configured that's overriding the DHCP-provided servers (and removing the override makes the correct DHCP-provided servers reappear).

Comment: You can check the DHCP hypothesis by running 'ipconfig getpacket en0' (replacing en0 with your primary interface). This will print out what you last got from DHCP.